# Beef installation 'libgcc-9-dev' not available. What do i do about it?

Tags: linux, exploit, kali-linux, beef

Note, selecting 'libreadline-dev' instead of 'libreadline6-dev'
Package libgcc-9-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libgcc-9-dev' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Error:- package has no installation candidate*

1. TYPE IN TERMINAL (`nano /etc/apt/sources.list`)
   DELETE ALL LINES INTO IT
2. GO TO  (`https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/`)

   *or*
3. copy repositories below mentioned
   COPY AND PASTE THESE LINES INTO SOURCE LIST

   ```
   {*deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib*

   *deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-last-snapshot main non-free contrib*

   *deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-experimental main non-free contrib*

   *deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib*}
   ```
4. TO EXIT AND SAVE press (`ctrl`+`x`) and press `Y` to confirm saving
5. Type `apt update` && `apt upgrade` in terminal

//hope it will work//